# Retrieve maximum number from alphanumeric column

Tags: sql

Please can someone help me with SQL query how to get maximum number from an alphanumeric field. Below is the code field. As you can see I want to retrieve the highest number for OSS which is 120. Thanks in advance.

```
ASG1
ASG10
ASG14
ASG2
ASG21
ASG4
LTS1
LTS10
LTS14
LTS2
LTS21
LTS4
OSS1
OSS10
OSS100
OSS11
OSS114
OSS120
OSS2
OSS21
OSS3
OSS4
OSS5
OSS6
OSS7
```

Comment: Please tag your dbms. Also, you want the highest number only for OSS or the highest number no matter which is the first 3 letters? Also, is it always 3 letters and then numbers?

Comment: Data you presented in question are in rows or stored as single column value.

Comment: Is it always 3 letters before the number?

Comment: Do you want 120, or OSS120 to be returned?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular Expression like this. It will work for every length of string and number.

```
    select column_name from table_name
      where REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,'[A-Za-z]','')= 
          (select max(to_number(REGEXP_REPLACE(column_name,'[A_Za-z]','')))  
               from table_name)
```

Comment: I appreciate all your efforts to helps me out , I tried yours and it returned OSS7 instead of the highest OSS120 . Below is the code please:     select MailRefNo from MailRegistry
      where REPLACE(MailRefNo,'[A-Za-z]','')= 
          (select max(REPLACE(MailRefNo,'[A_Za-z]',''))  
               from MailRegistry)

Comment: REGEXP_REPLACE() will replace all the charecter with  null and remaining number is treated as string. so we have to convert chareter to  number using `to_number()`. Try edited code